# jQuery Loop Through Elements In DIV

Tags: jquery, forms, dialog

I need to loop through elements in a DIV.  Specifically, the DIV is a dialog with form elements.  I want to loop through the elements in the DIV to make sure the required fields are filled in.  I know if I close the dialog and add it back into the DOM I can loop through the form elements but I don't want to close it until it's validated.  Can I do this or do I have to close it, check it, and then reopen it if there's a problem?

Comment: yes you can do it. Do it within event handler used to close dialog and don't close it if invalid

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you must loop all yours fields.

I'm using the **:input** selector, but you can use whatever you want.

```
var invalidFields=[];
$(":input").each(function(){

    // Check for the required property on the field
    if($(this).is(":required")){

        // Check if there is no value on the field
        if(!$(this).val()){
            invalidFields.push(this);
        }
    }
});
```

Then, just validate your Array too see if there is some field missing.

```
if (invalidFields.length>0){
    console.log("Fill the required fields!");
}
```

I could've just use a boolean instead of a Array, but you probably will need to iterate this array, so this code might be useful for you.

Note: Your html field must contain the required property.

```
<input type="text" required>
```